# Why does my iOS app get killed even though I ask for location updates in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location

My iOS app is sometimes getting killed even though I have put 'App registers for location updates' in the plist under 'Required background modes'.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 NSDate *dateEnteredIntoBackground = [NSDate date];

 FSLog(@"*** ENTERING BACKGROUND ***");

 [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ 

    NSDate *dateOfTermination = [NSDate date];              

}];
}
```

Whilst monitoring the above code, when it does get kicked out, the NSDate objects are always 10 minutes apart.

However: to make matters even more confusing, I am getting many occasions when the application is happy to run for over 30 mins in the background without terminating. As an additional test I have put the iPhone in a faraday cage, to ensure the location delegate updates are not getting called (this is confirmed by reading back a written log file); so it would seem that can be ruled out.

Any clues / advice?

Thanks

Carl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have to request new locations to prevent your app from being suspended. If you do not request a new location for a certain amount of time, iOS will suspend your app.

As workarounds, you can do the following:

- Continuously request a new location (at the latest in your expiration
  handler)
- Use the "significant-change location service", which will wake you up
  whenever the location changed

More details can be found in ["App States and Multitasking"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) and in ["Making your App Location Aware"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497), both part of the official Apple documentation.